# Capturing text and textarea fields at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the textarea and text boxes to capture in a text box. I was given a code to try which is:

`myForm.getElementsByTagName("select")` and `myForm.getElementsByTagName("textarea")`.

When I use these it completely breaks what I have now. In other words, it stops capturing everything. This is the function I am using below.

```js
function ShowText() {
  var inputs = myForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var notes = myForm.getElementsByTagName('notes');
  var box = document.getElementById('show');
  box.value = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    box.value += inputs[i].name + ': ' + inputs[i].value + '\n';
  }
}
```

```html
<b>Clicking Submit with gather the information above and copy to the box below. </b><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ShowText();">Submit</button><br>
<p>Show:</p>
<p><textarea cols=50 rows=10 id="show"></textarea></p>
<script>
  function copy() {
    let textarea = document.getElementById("show");
    textarea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
</script>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong but please help... This is driving me crazy.

Comment: can you share the form (I presume the one with `id="myForm"`)as well, to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Also `notes` are not a valid HTML tag